# find the dimension of $W_1 \cap W_2?$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have  some  confusion  on this   [You tube Video  solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Q34nAQ7Gcw?t=8m10s) Video timing  $8:10$ minute

In this video   answer  is $20$.

**Question**:  let  $W_1$  and  $W_2$  be the  subspaces  of the  real  vector  space of  $\mathbb{R}^{100}$  defined by

$W_1  =\{(x_1,x_2,.....,x_{100}):x_i=0  \text{if  i  is  divisible  by} \ 4\}$

$W_2  =\{(x_1,x_2,.....,x_{100}):x_i=0  \text{if  i  is  divisible  by}\ 5\}$.Then   find  the  dimension  of  $W_1 \cap W_2?$

My attempt : I get  the  answer  $95$

we know that he intersection of sets for two given sets is the set that contains all the elements that are common to both sets.

So i think $20 , 40,60,80,100$ divisible  by  both $4$ and $5$

Therefore $W_1 \cap W_2  =\{(x_1,x_2,.....,x_{100}):x_i=0 \  \text{if  i  is  divisible  by both }\ 5 \text{and} 4\}$

$\implies  \dim(W_1 \cap W_2)=100-5=95$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing $W_1\cap W_2$ with $W_1+W_2$. In fact, the $95$ you get should be the dimension of $W_1+W_2$. Then we apply
$$
\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=\dim W_1+\dim W_2-\dim(W_1+W_2).
$$